# What is in those numbers?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

" I am famous" declared Tom, flashing a newspaper.

> He showed me some scribbled numbers."Because of this, I made the
>   papers" He said.
>
> 8 = 4
>
> 8 = 3
>
> 6 = 2
>
> 6 = 3
>
> 3 = -1
>
> 5 = 1
>
> 5 = 0
>
> 1 = -2
>
> 7 = 3
>
> " I don't understand it but congratulations, Mr. Famous" I said
>
> "That's only part of it. It cost me a lot of money too! But I am
>   happy" Tom smiled.

What happened?

(and no, he did not pay the newspaper anything)

Hint 1

> The writings were on a **Scorecard**

Hint 2

> Only one of the row is the most important here

Comment: What happened to Grandpa? Is this grandpa when he was younger?

Comment: Ha Ha. Once you see the answer and check that against some of Grandpa's peculiarities you will understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Tom might be:

> A keen **golfer** (but not usually that great...)

The numbers represent:

> The number of strokes taken to complete each of the holes on a 9-hole course (or the opening 9 holes of an 18-hole course, if "that's only part of it"), followed by the score of that shot compared to par for the hole (i.e. the expected number of shots):
>
>  *Hole 1:* **8 = 4** (4 over par on a par-4 = 8 shots total)
>  *Hole 2:* **8 = 3** (3 over par on a par-5 = 8 shots total)
>  *Hole 3:* **6 = 2** (2 over par on a par-4 = 6 shots total)
>  *Hole 4:* **6 = 3** (3 over par on a par-3 = 6 shots total)
>  *Hole 5:* **3 = -1** (1 under par on a par-4 = 3 shots total)
>  *Hole 6:* **5 = 1** (1 over par on a par-4 = 5 shots total)
>  *Hole 7:* **5 = 0** (par on a par-4 = 5 shots total)
>  *Hole 8:* **1 = -2** (2 under par on a par-3 = 1 shot total)
>  *Hole 9:* **7 = 3** (3 over par on a par-4 = 7 shots total)

This means that one of the rows is particularly remarkable:

> That for Hole 8, where **1 = -2**, since this implies that on this hole he managed **to shoot a hole-in-one** (on a par-3 hole).

This achievement is especially remarkable considering:

> His game was all over the place in the holes leading up to this shot! I mean, seriously, he was 12 over par at that point!

Finally, to address Tom's comment that "It cost me a lot of money too" - this is likely because:

> He has probably spent a lot of money on golf lessons, tuition, equipment and golf club membership over the years. Still, it's finally all paid off and he now has a great story to tell in the clubhouse after a round! (EDIT: And - of course - as the OP pointed out in the comments, tradition dictates that a golfer who shoots a hole-in-one must buy a round of drinks in the clubhouse for EVERYONE... and trust me, those drinks aren't cheap...)

Comment: rot13(Qvq vg pbfg uvz n ybg bs zbarl orpnhfr tbys vf rkcrafvir?) :) +1

Comment: @ThatOneNerdyBoy rot(cebonoyl qhr gb yrffbaf, rdhvczrag naq tbys pyho zrzorefuvc) - but you're right, I should probably address that in my answer :)

Comment: @Stiv  Check with the Golfers. When you get Hole in 1 the tradition dictates that you buy drinks to every golfer on the course. VERY EXPENSIVE. Been there done that.

Comment: @DEEM Ah yes, of course! How could I forget that! (Facepalm)